# Pattern for doing a different thing based on which subclass is received?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, polymorphism

Currently I have something similar to the following data classes and I want the receiver of `CreateScheduledEventRequest` to perform different actions when `ScheduleInfo` is a `RepeatingTask` versus when it is a `OneShotTask`:

```
public record CreateScheduledEventRequest
{
    public ScheduleInfo ScheduleInfo = new OneShotTask();
}

public abstract record ScheduleInfo;

public record RepeatingTask : ScheduleInfo
{
    public TimeSpan RepeatEvery;
}

public record OneShotTask : ScheduleInfo
{
    public DateTimeOffset RunAt;
}
```

As an exercise in OOP-design I would also like to implement this without introspecting which subclass I have received. I tried naively to just create overloaded methods for each subclass, but I didn't manage to please the type-checker when calling them with the base class.

I'm hoping there is a way for me to write one method that takes a `RepeatingTask`, and another that takes a `OneShotTask`, and then somehow using C# language features dispatch to the correct implementation. I suspect maybe a strategy pattern can be used, but I'm worried that is a bit heavy for this little thing.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of how you "tried naively to just create overloaded methods for each subclass, but I didn't manage to please the type-checker when calling them with the base class" and the errors you got.

Comment: There is also dynamic dispatch in C#, though not sure I'm a fan of anything that uses dynamic :/

Answer (score 0):

To me it makes more sense to just change the design of your base class.
It does not seem efficient or smart to split these use-cases in different classes. Have a base class that does both and if you really must you can derive and mark members as obsolete.

Whats the benefit of having a third class choose how to execute something?

Implement a single class that does both.
You can use a bit flag / enum in a derived child class to mark what type of child class it is. This again just over complicates something rather simple in my eyes.

```cs
public abstract class ScheduleInfoBase
{
    public virtual TimeSpan RepeatEvery { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTimeOffset RunAt { get; set; }
    public virtual bool RunOnce { get; set; }

    protected virtual void RunAction(Action action)
    {
        if (RunOnce) {            
            // Execute once.
        }
        else {
            // Configure repetition pattern and run.
        }
    }
}


public class ScheduleInfoRunOnce : ScheduleInfoBase
{
    [Obsolete("Not implemented", true)]
    public override TimeSpan RepeatEvery
    {
        get {
            return default(TimeSpan);
        }
        set {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    [Obsolete("Not implemented", true)]
    public override bool RunOnce
    {
        get {
            return true;
        }
        set {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    protected override void RunAction(Action action)
    {
        //base.RunAction(action);
        action();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Implement a single class that does both."_ - Uncle Bob would probably say that's one thing too much. Also: having two ScheduleInfo Types to begin with, you can anticipate more to be added later... and then you will want to have little effort with ideally _no_ side effects on the existing implementations.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want an OOP Pattern: Visitor can do it...

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new CreateScheduledEventRequestHandler().Handle(new CreateScheduledEventRequest());
    }
}

public interface IScheduleInfoVisitor
{
    void Visit( IScheduleInfoHost host );
}

public interface IScheduleInfoHost
{
    void Host( RepeatingTask visitor );
    void Host( OneShotTask visitor );
}

public class CreateScheduledEventRequestHandler : IScheduleInfoHost
{
    public void Handle(CreateScheduledEventRequest request) => request.ScheduleInfo.Visit(this);
    public void Host( RepeatingTask visitor )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Repeat every {0}", visitor.RepeatEvery);
    }
    public void Host( OneShotTask visitor )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Run at {0}", visitor.RunAt);
    }
}


public record CreateScheduledEventRequest
{
    public ScheduleInfo ScheduleInfo = new OneShotTask();
}

public abstract record ScheduleInfo : IScheduleInfoVisitor
{
    public abstract void Visit( IScheduleInfoHost host );
}

public record RepeatingTask : ScheduleInfo
{
    public TimeSpan RepeatEvery;
    public override void Visit( IScheduleInfoHost host ) => host.Host(this);
}

public record OneShotTask : ScheduleInfo
{
    public DateTimeOffset RunAt;
    public override void Visit( IScheduleInfoHost host ) => host.Host(this);
}
```

In Action : https://dotnetfiddle.net/g5eJxM

You probably see at first glance that while it works, it comes with various caveats. So, I wouldn't actually *recommend* doing it like this.

This implementation is also the "verbose" version. You can hide some aspects of it by [implementing the host interface explicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation): https://dotnetfiddle.net/XfPfqj

If you introduced a little Generics, I could imagine a Mediator would work, too. Then you'd even have a Nuget ready at your disposal (MediatR, which I am not affiliated with).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of OOP this task is better done using aspect oriented approach. You can wrap those methods in classes if you want, though. For example lifetime state such as how much to execute (once, twice) can be either in memory or in some persistent storage. This approach is widely used in micro-service architecture, and even have library named "Polly":

```
public class Program
{

    public delegate Func<Task> AsyncExecutionPolicy(Func<Task> action, CancellationToken ct);
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var isExecuted = false;
        AsyncExecutionPolicy policy = (action, ct) =>
            () => ConditionalExecuteAsync(
                () => RunWithDelayAsync(action, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000), ct),
                () => !isExecuted,
                () => isExecuted = true);



        var myAction = async () => Console.WriteLine("Hello from method " + DateTime.UtcNow);

        var myActionWithPolicy = policy(myAction, CancellationToken.None);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from main " + DateTime.UtcNow);
        await myActionWithPolicy();
        await myActionWithPolicy();
        Console.WriteLine("DONE");
    }

    public static async Task RunWithDelayAsync(Func<Task> action, TimeSpan delay, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        await Task.Delay(delay, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await action().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    public static async Task RepeatAsync(Func<Task> action, TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await action().ConfigureAwait(false);
            await Task.Delay(interval, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

    public static async Task ConditionalExecuteAsync(Func<Task> action, Func<bool> shouldExecute, Action onSuccess)
    {
        if (shouldExecute())
        {
            await action().ConfigureAwait(false);
            onSuccess();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello from main 10/6/2023 8:22:40 AM
Hello from method 10/6/2023 8:22:45 AM
DONE
```

Comment: Sorry, but how does this answer OP's question?